# Boot layer initialization error when running RinSim examples on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, rinsim

I'm trying to get some RinSim examples running on IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2018.1.4. I've tried following the instructions on http://rinsim.rinde.nl/installation/intellij/,  but I run into the following error when performing step 11 in the guide:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /home/svka/.m2/repository/org/jppf/jppf-client/4.1.3/jppf-client-4.1.3.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.jppf.server.scheduler.bundle.providers.RLBundlerProvider not in module
```

The JDK I'm using is:

```
openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

JRE: `1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64`

Furthermore, I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.

The example runs on Eclipse, so I suppose there is something wrong with some settings in IntelliJ or something similar, but I have no clue on what to look for and can't find any similar posts by googling. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the exact same setup work on OpenJDK 10 when running it from the command line? E.g. using `mvn clean verify`

Comment: Do you mean running the command in the IntelliJ project folder or downloading rin-master from github and running it in that folder? 
Running it in the test/toy project works, but that doesn't give any runnable example files. 
Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok, try a command from the commandline in your own folder that runs your project. Just to confirm that your code runs in OpenJDK10 as the reference to modules in the exception might indicate a problem with that.

Comment: I changed to Java 1.8 and now it is working. Thank you for lending your support!